# Override Firefox makeFlags in Nixpkgs

Tags: nix, nixos, nixpkgs

I want to add a makeFlag to the Firefox package using Nixpkgs overlays, but it seems to be non-trivial.

### Overriding w3m works...

```
(import <nixpkgs> {
  overlays = [
    (self: super: {
      w3m = super.w3m.overrideAttrs (oldAttrs: {
        # that makeFlag makes no sense for w3m, it's just for demonstration
        makeFlags = oldAttrs.makeFlags ++ [ "BUILD_OFFICIAL=1" ];
      });
    })
  ];
}).w3m
```

### ...but overriding Firefox doesn't.

```
(import <nixpkgs> {
  overlays = [
    (self: super: {
      firefox = super.firefox.overrideAttrs (oldAttrs: {
        makeFlags = oldAttrs.makeFlags ++ [ "BUILD_OFFICIAL=1" ];
      });
    })
  ];
}).firefox
```

```
$ nix build -f default.nix
error: attribute 'makeFlags' missing, at /path/to/default.nix:5:21
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out, that one needs to override the `firefox-unwrapped` attribute:

```
(import <nixpkgs> {
  overlays = [
    (self: super: {
      firefox-unwrapped = super.firefox-unwrapped.overrideAttrs (oldAttrs: {
        makeFlags = oldAttrs.makeFlags ++ [ "BUILD_OFFICIAL=1" ];
      });
    })
  ];
}).firefox-unwrapped
```

That way the expression evaluates.